# How to: user AutoCompleteExtender in a UserControl (ascx) and place the ServiceMethod on its code-behind

Tags: user-controls, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit, pagemethods

I created a AutoCompleteExtender on a TextBox that resides on a UserControl (Control.ascx file).

I don't want to create a separate class for the web method, i rather placing it in the code file (Control.ascx.cs) itself.

Is there a way?

I have successfully tried once ago placing the method on the same **page** but it was a page, and if ServicePath property is not set it's automatically refered to the page so it worked, now since it's a user control it doesn't even when I explicitly specify the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually keep the web method in .aspx while other autocomplete extender related code can reside in .ascx. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The AutoCompleteExtender does not work within a UserControl at this time. Quoting Dino Esposito in MSDN Magazine Feb 2007: -

> *A callable page method is a public static (or Shared in Visual Basic.NET) method defined in the codebehind class and decorated with the same WebMethod attribute used for Web service methods. At present, **this is limited to ASPX pages-both inline and codebehind code**-but might be extended in the future to user controls and custom controls.*

My recent experience shows this still holds true.

I'm afraid that you're left with either implementing the method as a WebService or moving the functionality back up to the page.